# How to query against Dictionary contents in Azure CosmosDB/DocumentDB?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am storing objects in Azure CosmosDB from C# code. The properties of these objects are not fully defined when the application starts, so some may be added or removed at runtime. That is why I have a property "Attributes" of type Dictionary in the model class:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; }
```

But how do I write queries against the contents of this property? For example, I would like to write a query like:

```
documentQueryable
  .Where(doc => doc.Attributes.ContainsKey("City") && doc.Attributes["City"] == "NY");
```

However, this is not supported:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQueryException: Method 'ContainsKey' is not supported., documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/10.0.14393.0
```

Comment: Have you tried without Contains? i.e. `documentQueryable.Where(doc => doc.Attributes["City"] == "NY");` - documents with no `City` key at all shouldn't be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Cosmos DB is schemaless you don't need to check the key exists. If you change your code to the following it should work as expected:

`documentQueryable.Where(doc => doc.Attributes["City"] == "NY");`

Comment: Are there any options available for the dictionary key to be case insensitive?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work , you can read on the same from [`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.linq.documentqueryable.createofferquery.aspx)

```
documentQueryable.Where(doc => doc.Attributes["City"] == "NY");
```